# Revert last commit for one file and not the whole repo

Tags: git

I have a repo that has many commits. In Intellij I can see the commits that affected a file and the last three are mine. These commits are buried inside a long history of commits, but for that specific file they are the last three commits.

Is it possible to revert commits for one specific file?

Comment: Commits are immutable. You can create NEW commits without the file changes (in such a case, I would probably do a `git checkout rev -- file`, `git commit`, then `git rebase -i`); however, such changes "modify history" and create a divergent branch as *all children/descendant commits are also modified because every commit depends on it's ancestors*. If this is acceptable (it usually is not for a mainline, especially where [many] others are working) is a personal call. Alternatively, just do a "fixup commit" and leave everything in the past alone.

Comment: Diff commit 4 with commit 1 (the parent of the first of 3 commits you made), and revert the changes you made by using the diff tool to apply the relevant differences from commit 1?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the simplest thing you can do is to take back that specific file to how it was before the first of the 3 last revisions you are talking about.... too bad you won't be able to link to those 3 revisions.... but you might address them in the revision comment. So...

```
git checkout earliest-of-the-three-revisions~ -- path-to-file
git commit -m "Reverting file path-to-file

revisions x, y and z produced and undesired effect because of foo bar"
```

And that should be it.